# redshift - how to use listagg with information_schema.columns table

Tags: amazon-redshift, string-aggregation, listagg

I'm using redshift and would like to create a comma separated list of columns. I'm trying to grab the column names from information schema using `listagg`:

```
SELECT  
listagg(column_name,',') within group (order by ordinal_position) 
FROM    information_schema.columns
WHERE   table_schema = 'my_schema'
AND     table_name = 'my table';
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Function (listagg(text,text)) must be applied on at least one user created tables;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a work around I tested..

```
select listagg(column_name, ', ') within group (order by column_name)
from 
(
    select  
        a.attname::varchar as column_name, typname::varchar as data_type
    from
        pg_type t, 
        pg_attribute a,
        pg_class c,
        pg_namespace ns,
        (select top 1 1 from my_schema.my_table)
    where 
        t.oid=a.atttypid
        and a.attrelid = c.oid
        and c.relnamespace = ns.oid
        and typname NOT IN ('oid','xid','tid','cid')
        and attname not in ('deletexid', 'insertxid')
        and trim(relname) = 'my_table'
        and ns.nspname = 'my_schema'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not answer how to apply listagg on information_schema, I can recommend an alternative method of using listagg on the pg catalog tables instead.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT listagg(attname, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.attsortkeyord) AS "columns"
FROM pg_attribute a, pg_namespace ns, pg_class c, pg_type t, stv_tbl_perm p, pg_database db
WHERE t.oid=a.atttypid AND a.attrelid=p.id AND ns.oid = c.relnamespace AND db.oid = p.db_id AND c.oid = a.attrelid
AND typname NOT IN ('oid','xid','tid','cid')
AND ns.nspname = 'my_schema'
AND RTRIM(name) = 'my table'
```

Comment: which table does your name column belong to? I doubt this solution is working. @noober were you able to solve this question ?